# using OR in IIF statement...RDLC

Tags: report, rdlc, iif

Please can you someone help me?
My question is :

> How to use properly OR in IIF
>   statement in RDLC report?

Both Fields!A.Value and Fields!B.Value contains string or empty string.

This code works fine:

```
=Iif(Len(CStr(First(Fields!A.Value, "dsResult_dtRows")))=0, True, False)
```

This code doesnt work:

```
=Iif(Len(CStr(First(Fields!A.Value, "dsResult_dtRows")))=0 Or
 Len(CStr(First(Fields!B.Value, "dsResult_dtRows")))=0, True, False)
```

thanks a lot for ideas and answers
-marek-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should be able to concatenate the field values and test for the empty string instead of testing each value individually.

try

```
IIF(Fields!A.Value & Fields!B.Value = '',true,false)
```

for either empty returning true, try:

```
IIF(Fields!A.Value ='' or Fields!B.Value = '',true,false)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right,it works...but if only both Fields!A.Value and Fields!B.Value are empty strings.

Comment: ...but I need to have the result=true if A or B is empty. Not A and B. Im trying to work it out,using your sugestion,but unfortunately im not succesful.

Comment: oh, sorry.  thought you wanted both empty.  I'll edit my response